# Какой синтаксис регулярных выражений использует Apache?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, .htaccess, apache, apache2.4

Столкнулся с тем, что .htaccess игнорировал флаг `L` в `RewriteRule`, в результате чего возникал конфликт двух правил. Разбираться, в чём дело, было лень и я решил просто изменить регулярку для первого правила, чтобы оно никогда не пересекалось со вторым. Собственно, правила:

```
Если запрашиваем /<имя файла>.js, то отдать файл /public/scripts/<имя файла>.js
Если запрашиваем /lib/<имя файла>.js, то отдать файл /libs/js/<имя файла>.js
```

Следовательно, если первое правило **не будет** обрабатывать запросы, начинающиеся с `/lib/`, то и проблема пропадёт сама собой. Например, так:

```
RewriteRule ^(?<!lib\/)((.*)(\.js))$ public/scripts/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^lib\/(.*)(\.js)$ libs/js/$1$2 [L]
```

Мимо. Апач вообще такой конструкции не знает, не говоря уже про постоянные ошибки 500, которые вылезают в самых неожиданных местах. Зато работает вот такое правило (обнаружено случайно, благодаря опечатке):

```
RewriteRule ^lib\/(.*)(\.js)$ libs/js/$1$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(lib)?([^\/]*\.js)$ public/scripts/$2 [L]
```

С точки зрения известных мне регулярок конструкция, в начале второго правила, читается, как "начало строки **может** содержать подстроку `lib`", но Апач явно понимает её как-то иначе, так как в таком виде второе правило больше не конфликтует с первым. Я пробовал менять их местами, думая, что, может, просто заработал флаг `L`, но порядок данных правил на их поведение не влияет.

В связи с вышеперечисленным у меня вопрос: а какой вообще синтаксис регулярных выражений использует Апач (версия 2.4.7, если что)? И где можно найти по нему полную документацию?

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html

Comment: `(?<!lib\/)` - это блок предварительного просмотра назад. В [документации Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html#page-header) говорится о поддержке им регулярных выражений PCRE, в которых указанная вами конструкция *поддерживается*. Хотя вам на самом деле надо было использовать блок предварительного просмотра *вперед*, `RewriteRule ^(?!lib/)(.*\.js)$ public/scripts/$1 [L]`. Второй пример работает только потому, что `[^\/]*` находит 0+ символов, отличных от `/` (всё со слешем не будет обработано).

Comment: @Risto, флаг `L` не игнорируется. Если правило сработало с таким флагом, то дальнейшие правила не выполняются, НО (если не ошибаюсь) если это правило изменило запрос, то apache снова обрабатывает .htaccess с самого начала.

Comment: @Visman но ведь если правило срабатывает, оно по определению меняет запрос, или я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: @Risto, в английском не силен, но поведение такое странное. Тут на сайте есть много вопросов по этому поводу про зацикливание переадресации. Обычно решают через установку переменной, по которой определяют было ли уже изменение сделано или нет.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ваш код породил очередную ошибку 500 ;) И Википедия утверждает, что блок я выбрал верный. А вот на счёт причин работы кода вы были правы, спасибо.

Comment: Википедия утверждает, что `^(?<!lib\/)` правильно? Вы не понимаете этого выражения. Оно означает, что *перед началом строки не должно быть `lib/`*. Имеет это смысл? Это условие всегда верно!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew да, утверждает, и права: https://regex101.com/r/jAHn0j/2 А указанное вами поведение как раз соответствует `(?!)`.

Comment: Тогда как вы объясните https://regex101.com/r/jAHn0j/3? `^(?<!lib\/)` = `^`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew да, неудачный пример подобрал. Действительно, ошибалась Википедия, как показала проверка: https://regex101.com/r/jAHn0j/4

Comment: А, нет, Википедия тоже права, просто там просто там задача другая стояла.

Comment: Любые проблемы с htaccess начинайте с внимательного изучения материала: https://habrahabr.ru/company/sprinthost/blog/129560/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял

```
Если запрашиваем /<имя файла>.js, то отдать файл /public/scripts/<имя файла>.js
Если запрашиваем /lib/<имя файла>.js, то отдать файл /libs/js/<имя файла>.js
```

запрос к js файлам идет либо в корень, либо в папку lib, то сделайте так

```
RewriteRule ^lib/([^/]+)\.js$ /libs/js/$1.js [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.js$ /public/scripts/$1.js [L]
```

Comment: Только `([^/]*)`, а не `([^/])`, там же не по одному символу. Исправьте, пожалуйста, а то не-автору правку в два символа сделать нельзя, минимум 6. А так работает, спасибо. Не знал, что слеши не надо экранировать, удивился.

Comment: Тогда уж `([^/]+)`. Склероз :)